# How to detect if my image is truncated and load it thread-safely?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, truncated

I have an image processing function which makes an image's thumbnail and gets its width and height. I set `LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGE = True` to load truncated image.

```py
    from PIL import Image, ImageFile

    ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
    try:
        image = Image.open(buffer)
        image = image.convert('RGB')
        ...

    finally:
        ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = False
```

But because it's working on multi-thread, that global variable(LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGE) does not seem like thread-safe and sometimes fail to load truncated images and raise OSError.

What I want to do is

1. load truncated image thread safely.
2. raise OSError to alert the image is truncated.

Is there any way to solve these problem?

I saw related [PIL github issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3012)  and found that the only way is try-catch. So it would be nice if I can find another way to detect image truncation with or without PIL.

Comment: Maybe solve whatever is causing the truncated images...

Comment: It happens when users upload the truncated images on our service so that part cannot be solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention the type of your images:

- If they are JPEG, they must end with [EOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure), namely the two bytes `0xff 0xd9`
- If they are PNG, they must end with an [IEND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Critical_chunks) marker `49 45 4e 44 ae 42 60 82`

---

I can't get near a computer to test, but this should show the last 2 bytes of a JPEG in a BytesIO are `ff d9`

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

# Create black image
im = Image.new("RGB",(64,48))

# Put into a BytesIO
bytes = BytesIO()
im.save(bytes, format="JPEG")

# Check last 2 bytes
buff = bytes.getbuffer()
print(buff[-2:].hex())
```

And likewise for `PNG`:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

im = Image.new("RGB",(64,48))

bytes = BytesIO()
im.save(bytes, format="PNG")
buff = bytes.getbuffer()
print(buff[-8:].hex())
```

---

Alternatively, you can upload a JPEG/PNG to [hexed.it](https://hexed.it/) and inspect the last few bytes.

Comment: Sorry for lack of the information. All types you mentioned can be uploaded. Then could you explain how to read the bytes or marker of the file? I'm dealing with ByteIO buffer in this process. (by cloning azure blog storage stream)

Comment: I had an attempt at sample code by guessing without a computer - it should be pretty close.

Comment: Thank you so much!! At first it doesn't work because I did not set LOAD_TRUCATED_IMAGES= True. But when I set this True and get buffer it returns bytes which is different from EOI.

Comment: I have an another question..... Have you seen a case that extra bytes exist after EOI in JPEG file? I compared last 2 bytes to detect truncated JPEG images but not truncated JPEG file does not end with EOI. (like FF D9 00 00  01 0A .... ) I'm confused...  sorry for asking again :(