# How to find images with a variable sized grey rectangle (JPEG corruption) in them?

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg, corruption

I had to recover a hard drive and a lot of photos in it came out corrupted. I'm talking about 200.000 photos. I already wrote a script that finds corrupted JPEGs. But some of these images are not corrupted on a file format level. Yet they appear as the example I am showing. The grey part i suspect is data missing from the file. The grey part size is variable and sometimes it has an incomplete line in it.

So I'm thinking I could write or find  a script that finds grey rectangles in these images.

How do I do this? Something that opens the image data and looks for this giant grey rectangle? I have no idea where to start. I can code in a bunch of languages.

Any help/examples, is much appreciated.

[image: example of corrupted image]

Comment: you are trying to detect **corruption**, not just "a gray rectangle" -- if you're really asking about image processing techniques... please start by learning the basics

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68415308/2836621

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I just explained that it is not detected as corruption. please read again. i did the corruption check. Now I want an image content check. Please put the tags back!

Comment: ok fine. please review [ask]. your research should have included "image processing 101" type tutorials that cover "masks" and selection based on pixel color or a range of color values. please review [mre]. you show a recompressed version of such corrupt data. an original-resolution, losslessly compressed image would be better.

Comment: `exiftool` will probably tell you if they are corrupted. So can **ImageMagick** if you run `magick identify -verbose YOURIMAGE`

Comment: Note that the grey block probably doesn't actually exist in the image file. The viewer program likely reads the image header and determines the size of the image. It then allocates an empty, or flat grey buffer large enough to hold the image and starts decoding the stream of pixels. If there's an error, or if the image is incomplete or corrupt, it stops filling the buffer. At the end it shows the buffer on the screen. So hopefully you can see there is probably not a grey area in the image file to look for or process - it's just an unfilled artefact caused by incomplete/corrupt images.

Comment: yeah, best approach would be to instrument the decoding of the file, and take note of which areas of the canvas are actually painted with data, and which ones aren't. -- I've given one JPEG library a cursory look (a long while ago). it allows to install a callback for decoding and it also reports various errors. use the information. -- if you REALLY do have a picture that is actually complete, but is a recompression of a previously corrupt image file, that will require an actual image processing approach. I'm worried that you'll just latch onto the wrong approach for lack of better ideas

Comment: it's not really a recompression. at least not a lossless one. i think the jpegs format was somehow fixed before trying to remove true duplicates. As such they aren't detected as invalid jpegs anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking that the grey rectangle is always the same colour, so I created a function to see if that grey is one of the top 10 most frequent
colours.
If the colour had changed, then I would have adjusted the code accordingly to check if the top colour is at least 10x more frequent than the second most frequent colour.

Didn't have to learn feature detection this time. Shame. :(

```py
    from collections import Counter
    from PIL import Image

    # Open the image file
    image = Image.open(file)

    # Convert the image to RGB format (if it's not already)
    image = image.convert('RGB')

    # Get a list of all the pixels in the image
    pixels = list(image.getdata())

    # Count the number of pixels with each RGB value
    counts = Counter(pixels)

    most_common_colors =  counts.most_common(10)
    return (128,128,128) in [t[0] for t in most_common_colors]
```