# How can I catch corrupt JPEGs when loading an image with imread() in python?

Tags: python, jpeg, corruption

I`m talking about errors like *"Corrupt JPEG data: bad Huffman code"* or *"Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment"*. Currently, those count as some kind of warnings, not as errors and printed to **stderr**.
But I actually need to catch those errors. Some guy on stackoverflow provided a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26238635/18032315) by changing the source code of OpenCV, but I can't figure it out how to make it with Python. He even created a pull request on [github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/3314), but it was declined.

What I actually need is just to check jpg, jpeg, png files for integrity and corruption, which imread() provides, but I can't extract any useful data from the cv2 just printing it to **stderr**.

My current code:

```
from os import listdir
import cv2
import os
    
dir = './input/'
dest = './output/'
if not os.path.exists(dest):
        os.makedirs(dest)
        print('Output directory created')
for filename in listdir(dir):
        try:
            print(filename)
            img = cv2.imread(dir+filename)
        except cv2.error as e: print('Error: ' + str(e))
```

It is just prints the filename and if any integrity or corruption happens, cv2 prints it to **stderr**. I also tried to just redirect the output to another file like this:

> python main.py >> output.txt

And then somehow parse it, but I can only see my print, not that one from imread().

So, is there any solution to this problem? Because I tried a lot of corruption checkers, like Pillow verify() method or integv library. But only this one can properly see all my corrupted files.

Comment: Did you do any research? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74999718/2836621

Comment: there *are* ways to catch some library call's stdout/stderr output using Python (this is unrelated to OpenCV). you aren't asking about that though. you are asking for a library that tells you what's wrong with the image file (also unrelated to OpenCV).

Comment: @christoph-rackwitz, which are those ways? Firstly, I'm asking for a way to catch this stderr. If it is not possible, then I would like to see libraries that provide exact to OpenCV functionality with catching-possible. Because that output to stderr does exactly what I need. Tells if image has some problems with its structure. And currently, you can't just make an if statement for those.

Answer (score 0):

`imread()` is used to load an image from the specified file. It returns a numpy.ndarray (NumPy N-dimensional array) after loading the image successfully. For Corrupted Images, imread can't load properly, so won't helps here.

Pillow `verify()` raises an exception if there is a problem with the image and it can load image generous upto 85 Mpixels(this can be modified by `Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS`)

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image
   
for filename in listdir('./'):
  if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
    try:
      I = Image.open('./'+filename) # open the image file
      I.verify() # verify that it is, in fact an image
    except (IOError, SyntaxError) as e:
      print('Bad file:', filename) # print out the names of corrupt files
```

Comment: does your answer require the use of "base64"? if it does not, simplify.

Comment: StringIO and BytesIO will helps if image contains some different format data or unsupported characters in the files.

Comment: You don't need BytesIO constructed **from an open() call**. just pass the file object itself. -- StringIO for binary data (result of b64decode) is a terrible idea. -- all of that is beside the point of using pillow's `Image.verify()`, which requires an Image instance. The creation of that Image instance is secondary.

Comment: You could try to verify [that](https://ibb.co/Pt0Y0HX) image. Method with `Image.verify()` does not work for it. But you can clearly tell it's corrupted. And `imread()` loads it correctly, tells what's wrong with, and return a numpy.ndarra as expected. You just cannot interact with stderr, where those "what's wrong" sits.

Comment: that file isn't corrupted. that file is a re-encoding of a corrupted file.